# Split the window in TeXnicCenter Beta 2.0

Tags: texniccenter

I use Windows 7. I have a project open and a file from that project. I want to split the window using Window->Split to edit one part of the document while seeing another one. The split option is shaded (as in non-clickable). Any idea why?

Also, when I have many windows open the buttons Tile Horizontally and Tile Vertically do nothing. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'd [welcome](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) you again, but I hope you already feel welcomed!  Please, only one question per post.  Take a look at our [FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: :-) I kept them together because they are both in the same menu and clearly related. I'm sure solving one will solve the other one.

Comment: Thinking about it more, you're very likely right.  Have you tried opening more than one document?  Just a random guess, but it may be that you can't have two windows if you don't have two documents to view (even if one should view the output of the other).  It is beta, after all.

Comment: yes, I need to open a second document for the commands tile horizontally/vertically to make sense, but they don't work. If I try to open the same document twice (I thought of that) it does not open a new document because all in all the document is already opened.

Given that the window environment is usually controlled by Windows libraries I start to suspect it might just be a bug, but I thought I would give it a try here before _bugging_ the developers, in case it isn't a bug.

Comment: I meant open two *separate* documents

Comment: Yes, I understood you. The button split still appears shaded after opening two separate documents. In any case split is not useful to most people with two different documents but with one only.

Comment: My apologies.  And don't think you'd be bugging the developers at all!  If it's a bug, they'll fix it.  If it's not, they'll make the documentation more clear.  (All feedback is appreciated!  We often get so little...)  The feature works as expected in 1.x, I presume? It's unlikely that they would have intentionally changed this part of the interface if it did exist.

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't have 1.x anymore :-( In the 1 beta the search tool use to go back to the beginning of the document and it doesn't anymore in the v2 (I reported this in the alpha stage but they didn't fix it, so I guess they like it that way).

Comment: @Jesus is [this thread](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?647299-How-to-do-Windows-7-split-window-feature) work for you ?

Comment: @texenthusiast not exactly, but I didn't know that, so thanks for letting me know. My problem is with the windows "inside" texniccenter. The answer below solves all the problems but the splitting one (which is the one I care the most about.

Answer (score 2):

This surely sounds like a bug, which [you should report](http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/user-reports/). Regardless, here's how to achieve what you're after (to some extent) when in "document tab" view.

With TeXnicCentre 2.0 Beta 1 a drag-and-drop of the opened files initiates the tiling. So, given a setup like

[image]

click on LaTeX3 and drag it into the code just below it to make it tile. Dragging it to the bottom provides a horizontal tiling

[image]

while dragging it to the right/left provides a vertical tiling

[image]

To restore the tiling, drag it back to the *tabs* of the files listed files. Out of "document tab" view (View > Document Tabs > Off)

[image]

tiling works as expected, both vertically

[image]

and horizontally

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is great and it solves the tiling. Thanks a lot. The buttons are still dumb, so it is definitely a bug.

I guess you have the same problem as I do in the splitting? You are using the same version as I am and your windows look a lot as Windows 7 to me. If you do, please let me know. It is driving me crazy to write an appendix at the same time as a chapter.

Comment: @Jesus: I am using the same version as you. As mentioned in my updated answer, the "Document tab" view is the culprit that fixes the view and avoids tiling. If you turn of "Document tab" view, then you can cascade and tile the windows to your liking.

Comment: Hi, wow I didn't know about the 'view' options. Thanks. Unfortunately they don't solve the splitting problem. Do you also have it? Thanks a lot for your answers!